# How do i link to images not in Static folder in flask

Tags: python, flask

In flask, how do I serve images that are not in the static folder?

I currently save the user uploaded photos on a directory that is outside the flask folder (On `openshift`, image currently saving in the data folder under `app-root/data` and the flask files are in `app-root/repo/`).

In my templates, how do i serve the image files ?

Using `url_for`, how do i reference these image files that are outside the flask folder?

```
- data/
 |
  -- uploads/
- repo/
 |
  -- app/
    |
     -- __init__.py
```

As you can see the data folder outside the flask app folder. How do i generate links to files stored in `data/uploads` (one level up) from the flask app directory is the question ?

Comment: Could please provide the structure of your project (directory tree) and the solutions that you have already tried?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have the **[send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory)** function that does what you want, what I would do is declare a constant called **MEDIA_FOLDER** with the path where the media files are located and then, the only thing you need to do is to call the function like this:

```
from config import MEDIA_FOLDER

@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(MEDIA_FOLDER, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Then, to invoke it, you just do this:

```
{{ url_for('download_file', filename='dogs.jpg') }}
```

You can have more info about this [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how would i go about getting the link for the file using url_for ?

Comment: @sarul I just edited the post, but basically you just have to do    {{ url_for('download_file', filename='dogs.jpg') }}}    for example.

Comment: im trying to reference the url_for in the src part of my img tag and still cant seem to get it to work. I updated my question with the file structure. Im essentially trying to generate file paths for files stored in data/uploads from the flask app which is stored in another directory

Comment: Check your MEDIA_FOLDER path, because the path should always be MEDIA_FOLDER + img/dogs.jpg for example, just like the url for static content works.For your app structure, the MEDIA_FOLDER should have something like this: `MEDIA_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))), 'data')`

Comment: Thanks Leandro for that. I was hardcoding the path of the media folder and couldnt get it to work. When i switched it with the os.path, dirname function you mentioned above, it worked !