# Do I need a generator, maybe SQLAlchemy for flask loop when querying SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, blob, generator

I am trying to query SQLite and return image paths that meet a certain condition in a flask for loop but I am getting a broken image icon. The image_path is saved into the SQLite table which I thought was a good solution here. The code I am using is below. The first set is where I am having trouble and the second set works when the images are saved to a `static` directory. Do I need to create a generator for this or I am just blundering somewhere else? This is what the SQLite table looks like,

[image]

**Edit 1**

I think it may help to explain what I want here. I want `index.html` to show a **Recent Ad** section which would display recently posted ads, like on [Adverts](https://www.adverts.ie/)

**app.py***

```
@app.route("/")
def index():

sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
ads = cursor.execute("SELECT image_path FROM food WHERE active = 'Y'")
ads = cursor.fetchall()
print(ads)

return render_template("index.html", ads=ads)
```

This is the output for `print(ads)`

`[('/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan.jpg',), ('/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan3.jpg',)]'

and this next is the results for the code

```
for row in ads:
    print(*row, sep='\t')
```

/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan.jpg

/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan3.jpg

**index.html**

```
{% for ad in ads %}
     <img src={{ad}}>
{% endfor %}
```

This yields the broken icon image. I have also tried adding `ads.

I am able to display images when jpegs are saved to the `static` directory with the follow code, but I am having a problem [with saving to the static folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591706/os-path-join-disrupting-function) so I am trying to figure out a work around just in case.

**app.py**

```
ads = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "images"))
return render_template("index.html", ads=ads)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for ad in ads %}
      <img src='/static/images/{{ad}}'/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971491/how-do-i-link-to-images-not-in-static-folder-in-flask

Comment: Well that answer calls the photos from a directory so I already have that working. What I wanted to know is if I could call them with a SQL query because, I want the picture to be 'active' (meaning the Y from the active column). I assumed that is why I would need a generator for that.

Comment: You seem to be missing quotes around the image links. Have you tried: `<img src='{{ad}}'>`

Comment: That is not it either. I tried the quotes inside and out. I tried the below

`for row in ad: print(*row, sep='\t')`

which prints. 

`/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan.jpg`
`/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan3.jpg`
`/home/ubuntu/final/freeood/dan.jpg`

I believe that is what a generator / `yield` would return so I might try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image files should be in the `static` folder of your website. This is because all file paths are relative to the root of your website.

There is, however, a work around if you really need to access files outside of your website using [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

Add this function to **app.py**:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/uploads/<path:img_path>')
def download_file(img_path):
    directory, filename = img_path.rsplit('/', 1)
    return send_from_directory(directory, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Then you can invoke this function in your template **index.html**:

```
{% for ad in ads %}
  <img src="{{ url_for('download_file', img_path=ad) }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry this just is not what I am looking for. It's a neat solution but when accessing `index.html` path, I want there to be a Recent Ads section that shows images of recently posted ads. That is why I want to query the `active` column in the SQLite table and why I have saved the path of the image to the SQLite table.

Comment: @SozDaneron *"I want there to be a Recent Ads section that shows images of recently posted ads"* You didn't state that in the original question. You're database query is getting only ads that are active. I guess you want ads that are inactive too? Then you could pass in another list into your template.

Comment: No, just the active images. I've made some edits to the original question.

Comment: I am coming back to accept this answer because after a few iterations, I am keeping the images in the `static` folder. What I did was change the name of the jpg when saving. I am able to query SQLite and then call any images this way. I was not able to serve the image from SQLite even with the path saved though. The `send_from_directory` also worked but `static` folder is the way to go.

Comment: @SozDaneron Sounds like a good solution. Sometimes these things only come after a few iterations!